# Automapper and database or service lookups

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I have a model passed into an action method.

```
class CustomerFront
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerType { get; set; }
    //snip...
}
```

An example would be `{"FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Smith", "CustomerType": "Corporate" }`

And a domain object with a similar shape -

```
class CustomerBack
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int CustomerType { get; set; } // Note this is an int
    //snip...
}
```

Automapper will easily map FirstName and LastName.

But I need to perform web service call passing `CustomerFront.CustomerType` to find out what the `int` value should be for the `CustomerBack.CustomerType`.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Automapper maps `string` to `int` and back by default.

Comment: I need to look up what int to use by calling a web service, calling  web service from inside an automapper profile doesn't seem like the right thing to do.